# Turtlebot calibration(Still waiting for imu/scan)

Tags: calibration, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I type "roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch", the terminal shows

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820084.864965] Estimating imu drift
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.165909] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.466922] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.767989] Still waiting for imu
```

Eariler on, it showed

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820084.864965] Estimating imu drift
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.165909] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.466922] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1308820085.767989] Still waiting for scan
```

Does anybody know what these two messages might suggest? I can't understand the code.

Extra info:

-Using a bumblebee2 camera instead of a kinect

-I am using a MicroStrain 3DM-GX2 IMU for turtlebot, I changed the frame_id to gyro_link and the remapped the topic "imu/data" robot_pose_ekf subscribes  to to "bumblebee2/bumblebee2/imu/data" so that the imu messages can reach robot_pose_ekf. Despite doing this, I'm not sure if the gyro is working properly as I still get "Bad Gyro Calibration" under diagnosis

Let me know if you require and extra information, I'm not too sure what is relevant. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10368/turtlebot-calibration(still-waiting-for-imu/scan)/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the calibration tool is expecting the imu under the standard topic. When you remap it, it cannot find that anymore as no one is publishing there.

You can change the remapping back to the original or if you don't want that, change the calibration launch script (or make your own) to remap to your imu topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot publishes two IMU data streams, imu/data and imu/raw.  Where the raw one is unfiltered and the imu/data is bias compensated.  This is allows for better performance with the cheap IMU used on the TurtleBot.

The calibration uses the imu/raw and estimates the bias.  You will need to remap the input to the calibration to match the output of your 3dmgx.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1